# React.js - get response from a POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [calculatedData, setCalculatedData] =useState(""); 

const calculateOrder = async() =>{

    try{
        
        const dataBody = `json=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(testInfo))}`;

        const responseObj = await fetch('API', {

            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: dataBody
        });

        const res = await responseObj.json();
        setCalculatedData(res);
        console.log(res); // Perfectly display data

    } catch(e){

        console.log(e)
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to save the response data to 'calculatedData', but I only get an empty string. Can anyone provide me any suggestion?

```
console.log(calculatedData) //Empty string
```

Comment: doubt: where are you printing `calculatedData` ?

Comment: I tried everywhere before rendering

Answer (score 0):

`useState` (or `setCalculatedData`) is asynchronous(just like `setState`) and changes would not be reflected immediately. As the data is not stored yet in the `calculatedData` when you console it, you would only receive the empty string.
Please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/11766947) for more information